# Keras LSTM input shape is wrong

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to create simple RNN in Keras which will learn over this dataset:

```
x_train = [
    [0,0,0,1,-1,-1,1,0,1,0,...,0,1,-1],
    [-1,0,0,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,...,-1,-1,0],
    ...
    [1,0,0,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,...,-1,-1,0]
]
```

which 1 means an increase in one metric and -1 means decrease in it and 0 means no change in the metric. Each array has 83 items for 83 metrics and the output (labels) for each array is a categorical array that shows the effect of these metrics on a single metric:

```
[[ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.],
 [ 0.  0.  1.],
 ...
 [ 0.  0.  1.],
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

I used `Keras` and `LSTM` in the following code:

```
def train(x, y, x_test, y_test):
    x_train = np.array(x)
    y_train = np.array(y)
    print x_train.shape
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 3)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(128,input_dim=83, input_length=3))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    opt = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-2)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=opt,
            metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=200)
```

The output of line `print x_train.shape` is `(1618, 83)` and when i run my code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 171, in <module>
    load()
  File "temp.py", line 166, in load
    train(x, y, x_test, y_test)
  File "temp.py", line 63, in train
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=200)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 652, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1038, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 963, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 100, in standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
Exception: Error when checking model input: expected lstm_input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1618, 83)
```

I don't want to use `Embedding` and want to add `input_shape` to the `LSTM` layer.

Comment: Is this problem a time series problem? Does each value in a row depend on the previous value in the same row?

Comment: @djk47463 each row in the `x_train` array is for a specific date. and each item in each date is represented `increase(1)`, `decrease(-1)` or `no change(0)` for one of each `83 metrics` in that date. so, for example, `item 20` from `row 10` does not depend on both `item 20` from `row 9` or `row 11` and `item 19` or `item 20` in `row 10`. and y is the effect of these `83 metrics` on one single metric on the same date as the row's date.

Comment: Then it does not make sense to use an LSTM. While neural nets are interesting, they are also very complex. If you do not know enough about them to understand the different applications of different layers, my suggestion would be to do more research. ANN's are one algorithm for ML, there are many more, simpler ones that will help build your understanding in this field. Otherwise @Matias Valdenegro answered the question correctly. You data needs to be 3D

Answer (score 1):

LSTM is a recurrent layer, meaning the input data has to be three dimensional, which corresponds to a two-dimensional input shape. In practice this means that the data must have shape `(num_samples, timesteps, features)` and the input shape must be `(timesteps, features)`.

In your case you are missing the timesteps dimension in both your data and input shape.

Comment: @EmadHelmi In your case features seems to be 83, but as LSTM processess sequences, the timesteps dimension defines the length of the sequences, and your data does not seem to be a sequence, so I am not sure.

Comment: @EmadHelmi The problem is not the library but the specific algorithm you chose.

Comment: Which algorithm do you think that is better for this problem?